# Streaming FPV over WiFi?

Tags: first-person-view

I met a guy some time ago running a first person view (FPV) stream over Wifi. He said that the setup didn't use a complete [Operations System Interconnect (OSI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) network stack and this allowed them to stream video faster then one might over [User Datagram Protocol (UDP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol). I don't recall the details but at the time he said it was a common trick used by Drone flyers, perhaps this was just the group he knew. I was wondering if anyone had any further information on this. I believe he was streaming 4K and was quite surprised. At the time I was messing around with a an early Raspberry PI and trying to stream video myself but I could only achieve a speed/quality that where far inferior by comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done by placing streaming video data (RTP) directly into the Wi-Fi frames. Checkout https://github.com/svpcom/wifibroadcast/ project for more details.

Comment: Thank you ! It is interesting that the fork employs UDP. I have been wanting to try this out on a ESP8266 for some time now.